# How to show image preview from GridView Activity in Android

Tags: android, image, gridview

I made a App with a GridView using this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Grid2.html) for android.  I placed all the images 
into the drawable-hdpi folder. The gridview is working just fine but now i want to start or open another activity when the user touches an image in the gridview. The new activity should be a preview of that single image.

How can I do this?

This how i putted but its not working 
my 1activity :

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {                
        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), 2activity.class);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra(1activity.class.getName(),imageIDs);

        1activity.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent); 
    }
});
```

my 2activity :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int[] imageIDs) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.image);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        long imageIDs = (Long) intent.getExtras().get(2activity.class.getName());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.preview);

        imageView.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        imageView.setImageResource((int) imageIDs);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);     

    }
```

when i go to 2activity from 1activity its just showing nothing just blank its not catching images from 1st activity ???? what shall i do ???

Answer (score 1):

Error here:

```
long imageIDs = (Long) intent.getExtras().get(2activity.class.getName());
```

wrong key, fix it by:

```
 long imageIDs = (Long) intent.getExtras().get(1activity.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an OnItemClickListener ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html ) that launches your activity and use the setOnItemClickListener method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) to attach the listener to your GridView.

-Kurtis

Comment: Thanks Kurtis i tried that link but its not working so can plz tell me in detail how to call gridview images from 1activity to 2activity if you don't mind b'coz i'm newbie in android

Comment: Try checking this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html . Scroll down to the bottom check out how they set the onItemClickListener. You're gonna want to do the same thing, except instead of creating a toast, you want to create an Intent with the activity you want to launch and call startActivity().

Comment: I'm still not getting it i tried that and its working but when i go to 2activity but its just showing nothing just blank its not catching images from 1st activity ???? what shall i do ???

Comment: In the Intent that you create to start the new activity, you'll have to include a reference to the image and then in the new activity you'll have to create some sort of view to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2Activity you are getting null value for

```
long imageIDs = (Long) intent.getExtras().get(2activity.class.getName());
```

you should put here:

```
int imageIDs1 = intent.getIntExtra(2activity.class.getName(), R.drawable.icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Image click Get Image Bitmap, Convert bitmap to Bytes and pass bytes via intent to your activity

```
                Bitmap b=image.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,75, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ShowImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Bitmap", bytes);
                startActivity(i);
```

In 2nd Activity Get Bytes from bundle and set to imageview

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if(bundle.containsKey("Bitmap")) {
            byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("Bitmap");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
            photo.setBackground(ob);
        }

    }
```